# override default methods in interface and execute the default method in interface

Tags: java

I want to execute the defined body of a default method in interface by creating an object of concrete implementation class which has also overridden the method. Whether I create the object of concrete implementation class directly or whether through dynamic binding/polymorphism , the body defined/ overriden in the implementation class is only getting executed.
Please see the below code

```
interface Banking 
{
    void openAc();
    default void loan()
    {
    System.out.println("inside interface Banking -- loan()");
    }

}

class Cust1 implements Banking
{
    public void openAc()
    {
        System.out.println("customer 1 opened an account");
    }

    public void loan()
    {
        // super.loan(); unable to execute the default method of interface 
        //when overridden in implementation class
         System.out.println("Customer1 takes loan");
    }
}//Cust1 concrete implementation class

class IntfProg8 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Object type=Banking \t\t\t Reference type=Cust1");
        Banking banking = new Cust1();
        banking.openAc();
        banking.loan();
    } 
}
```

I want to know how to print the following in console 
inside interface Banking -- loan()

when the default method is overridden

Comment: The fact of putting the interface name on the left hand side of the object creating has NO effects on the created object. Unrelated: use the @Override annotation when overriding!

Answer (score 1):

`Banking.super.loan()` would call the `Banking` interface `default` method.

Comment: Generally static methods are called wrt to interface name . I am reading this syntax for the first time interfaceName.super.methodName. I checked and executed the code, it is working , but can you please explain the concept/logic behind it, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
class Cust1 implements Banking {
public void openAc() {
    System.out.println("customer 1 opened an account");
}
public void loan() {
    Banking.super.loan();
    System.out.println("Customer1 takes loan");
}
}
```

Comment: Generally static methods are called wrt to interface name . I am reading this syntax for the first time interfaceName.super.methodName.
I checked and executed the code, it is working , but can you please explain the concept/logic behind it,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add an explanation.